Extracting certain formate data fromexcel using python
#After exporting data into date frame it looks like below



data 1





id
datum


2000
2024.09.02


2903
2024.09.02


data 2



id
datum


4000
2024.09.02


4001
2024.09.02



#expected answer should look like this



id
datum
data




2000
2024.09.02
1


2903
2024.09.02
1


4000
2024.09.02
2


4001
2024.09.02
2



import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Step 1: Read the Excel file
# Replace 'your_file_path.xlsx' with the actual path to your Excel file
file_path = 'your_file_path.xlsx'

# Load the Excel file
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)

# Assuming 'Datei2' is the name of the sheet we want to read
df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name='Datei2')
df['Column1 - Copy'] = df['Column1']
split_columns = df['Column1 - Copy'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
split_columns.columns = [f'Column1 - Copy.{i+1}' for i in range(split_columns.shape[1])]
df = pd.concat([df, split_columns], axis=1)

# Step 6: Fill Down Values
df['Column1 - Copy.16'] = df['Column1 - Copy.16'].fillna(method='ffill')


Please, take some time to read how to ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

What is the point of the added code? Your sample doesn't have any of these columns. Please [edit] your question to fix the code so that it meaningfully fits your sample data, and explain how it relates to either input or desired output.

Assuming your excel file looks exactly like you put, you can use cumsum to put your data into groups and then remove any unnecessary data by filtering the dataframe:
df = pd.read_excel(<your file>, header=None, names=['id', 'datum'])

       id       datum
0  data 1         NaN
1      id       datum
2    2000  2024.09.02
3    2903  2024.09.02
4  data 2         NaN
5      id       datum
6    4000  2024.09.02
7    4001  2024.09.02


df['data'] = (df['datum'].isna()).cumsum()

        id       datum  data
0  data 1         NaN     1
1      id       datum     1
2    2000  2024.09.02     1
3    2903  2024.09.02     1
4  data 2         NaN     2
5      id       datum     2
6    4000  2024.09.02     2
7    4001  2024.09.02     2

df = df[~df['datum'].eq('datum')].dropna(how='any')

     id       datum  data
2  2000  2024.09.02     1
3  2903  2024.09.02     1
6  4000  2024.09.02     2
7  4001  2024.09.02     2


df = pd.read_excel(, header=None, names=['id', 'datum']) if i create names then it recognize only first 2 rows as 1 and doesnot recognize second datum then it assign continues number 1,1,then2 3, 4 for this df['data'] = (df['datum'].isna()).cumsum()

import pandas as pd

##### Step 1: Read the Excel file (replace 'your_file_path.xlsx' with the actual file path)
file_path = 'your_file_path.xlsx'

##### Assuming the data spans multiple blocks in a single sheet
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=None)

##### Step 2: Identify blocks of data and label them
##### A block starts with "data X" where X is the block number
df['block'] = df[0].str.extract(r'data (\d+)').ffill()

##### Step 3: Remove rows that are not part of the main data
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('data', na=False)]

##### Step 4: Rename columns and clean up the DataFrame
df.columns = ['id', 'datum', 'block']
df = df.dropna(subset=['id', 'datum'])

##### Step 5: Clean and format the columns
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(int)
df['datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datum'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
df['block'] = df['block'].astype(int)


String could be some times not just  Data X but some of the rows will have data like "Data extract from 2/45 data 3".I dont need separate number in the data coloumn just replacing data1,data2 would work
